# Почему оператор "^" в if, выдает неправильное значение?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, битовые-операции

Задача заключается в том чтобы в заданном `char` массиве вывести знак который повторяется всего один раз.
Пример: в массиве `aabcb`, вывести `c`.
Во входных данных всегда будет максимум один такой знак. Первая строка входных данных будет числом, указывающим на количество элементов массива `n` `(1 ≤ n ≤ 100000)` Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main() {
int n;
char arr[100001];
char lost;
bool hasPair;
scanf("%d\n", &n);
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    printf("Ok");
    return 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
scanf("%c", &arr[i]);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    hasPair = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            continue;
        }
        if (arr[j] ^ arr[i] == 0) {
            hasPair = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasPair) {
        lost = arr[i];
        break;
    }
}
printf("%c\n", lost);
return 0;
}
```

Этот код выводит неправильный ответ и поэкспериментировав я понял что проблема в блоке

```
if (arr[j] ^ arr[i] == 0) {
    hasPair = 1;
    break;
}
```

Я вывел значение `arr[j]` внутри него и выяснил, что программа заходит в этот блок всегда, и всегда `arr[j]` равен `arr[0]`.
Почему так происходит и как можно исправить код?

Comment: взял просто скомпилировал код и запустил - http://ideone.com/IH0UuR
работает как ожидается.

Comment: если в входных данных искомый знак ставить последним, то работает. В остальных случаях-нет

Comment: а зачем у вас вот эта проверка: `if (n % 2 == 0)` ? То есть одинаковых знаков не может быть, например, 3? Всегда повторяющихся по два?

Comment: да, всегда по два. По условию задачи, если у всех знаков есть пара, то выводится "Ok"

Comment: с приоритетами проблема. Пишите так `if ((arr[j] ^ arr[i]) == 0) {`, а лучше вообще так `if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {`

Comment: Да, точно. Дело было в приоритетах

Comment: Мне кажется, что этот алгоритм неправильный. В задачах такого типа обычно пишут, что все нужно сделать за один проход. Правильное решение - взять XOR сумму от всех элементов массива. Тогда может получиться два варианта:
1. все элементы одинаковы - XOR сумма =  0
2. один элемент повторяется нечетное количество раз - XOR-сумма = значение этого элемента. Вот его и выводите. Не номер элемента, а его значение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C (и в C++ тоже) операции сравнения (`< <= > >= == !=`) имеют более высокий приоритет, чем битовые операции. Поэтому компилятор воспринимает приведенный код как

```
if (arr[j] ^ (arr[i] == 0))
```

А, с учетом приведения к булевому типу:

```
if ((arr[j] ^ (arr[i] == 0)) != 0)
```

Во входных данных содержатся символы, т.е. значения, отличные от нуля. Поэтому результатом сравнения будет 1, с которым выполняется битовый XOR другого символа (код которого вряд ли равен 1 - этот код не соответствует отображаемым символам).
Поэтому данное условие всегда истинно.

То есть этот код можно заменить на

```
if (!(arr[j] ^ arr[i]))
```

или

```
if ((arr[j] ^ arr[i]) == 0)
```

Но вообще применение битовых операций в данном случае мне видится неоправданным. Эту же конструкцию можно записать так:

```
if (arr[j] == arr[i])
```

что будет более читабельно и меньше подвержено ошибкам.

Answer (score 2):

Как известно, в *C++* имеются приоритеты операций. Если посмотреть на [таблицу приоритетов](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), то мы увидим, что у оператора сравнения `==` приоритет 9, а у исключающего или `^` - 11. Поэтому выражение

```
arr[j] ^ arr[i] == 0
```

будет интерпретировано как

```
arr[j] ^ (arr[i] == 0)
```

То есть вначале `arr[i]` будет сравнено с нулём. Поскольку проверяются символы до конца строки, то это условие всегда будет ложным, то есть `false`. Согласно правилам преобразования, `false` будет преобразовано к нулю и условие превратится в

```
arr[j] ^ 0
```

Но это то же самое, что и просто `arr[j]`. Вновь вступают в силу правила преобразования и `arr[j]` преобразуется к типу `bool`, что даёт `true`, поскольку `arr[j]` не является нулевым символом.

Итак, мы получили, что условие всегда выполняется. Чтобы исправить ситуацию, нужно расставить приоритеты самостоятельно, используя скобки:

```
(arr[j] ^ arr[i]) == 0
```

Но более правильным будет не использовать эту конструкцию, а написать просто

```
arr[j] == arr[i]
```

---

P.S. Кстати, я бы на Вашем месте выделял память для `arr` не в стеке, а в куче, динамически. И ровно столько, сколько потребовал пользователь, без запаса.